# Is it suitable if Builder Pattern construct object from database value instead of parameter input

Tags: c#, design-patterns, builder, fluent, facade

Planning to use builder pattern but, I am not sure its right way to use or not.
here,
1) pull data from database Or API and construct object 2) post to API

so, It looks like, this suite to Builder design pattern as follow:

I did not see example where builder pattern is used to construct object by reading data from database. Is it suitable pattern while constricting object from database or API retrieved data OrElse, its wrong design ?
Example:

```
public class ResultBuilder
{

    private IList<Parts> _parts; 
    private IList<Dealers> _dealers;

private int resultSetId;
    public ResultBuilder(int resultSetId)
    {
        this.resultSetId = resultSetId;
    }

    public ResultBuilder PrepareParts()
    {
        //call to PartsService and pull from database based on resultSetId and prepare List<Parts>.

    }
public ResultBuilder PrepareDealer()
    {
        //call to DealerService and pull from database and prepare List<Dealer>.

    }

    public IList<Dealers> Build()
    {
        //Build Dealers and Parts mapping for Dealer.Parts and return;
        //submit to another service.
    }
}
```

client:   `ResultBuilder.PrepareParts().PrepareDealer().Build();`

Answer (score 1):

The main issue with making the builder populate the object this way is that your builder will **only** be able to create things this way.

For example, next month, you may find that you need to build one of those objects with similar data sourced from somewhere else.

It would be more flexible to keep a [separation of concerns](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns) (or *"single responsibility principle"*: the S from [SOLID](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID)) by keeping the builder as a builder, and using a different class to coordinate fetching the data and passing it to the builder.

Is it *"wrong design"* to do it the way you described? Design decisions are very subjective, and should be based on the known and expected requirements at that point in time. For example, design principles *against* doing what I've suggested are [YAGNI](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/You_aren%27t_gonna_need_it) and [Rule of Three](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_three_(computer_programming)).

In other words, you have to balance the increase in flexibility with the increase in quantity of the code.

Comment: here, on client method, first pull the `resultSetId` and then passing to `resultBuilder` to build Parts, Dealers and Build to (submit & return response).  Internally, PrepareParts will call the PartsService to interact with repository and pull the data and same for PrepareDealers.  But, client method (Main[])  will only pass `resultSetId` and no any paramter further to construct object. Is it realistic scenario Or, I have to call partsService or dealerService from client method (Main[]) itself and not to use with builder Pattern ?

Comment: Also basically, here its one object to build and prepare by calling different `serviceRepository`.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure you can "build" a Dealer unless this is a shop. Rather, have the Dealer as a Director object which calls its own Construct method that accepts a Builder object as a parameter.

A builder pattern requires a Director class composed of 1 or more Builder classes. Builder classes produce Parts.

You can make an abstract Builder class and have concreted builders for Motorcycle, Car or Ship parts. These builders provide a method to return the Product they host which are the parts in this instance.

Answer (score 0):

You should consider whether that the steps `PrepareParts().PrepareDealer()` are mandatory or not, and whether they can be omitted or not. And, for that matter, whether the order of operations is important.

If all of the steps are mandatory and if you must do it in order then a builder is not a great way to go.

The next thing you should consider is whether you want to change the provider of the data for your steps. Then you need some sort of dependency injection into your builder. You might want to source from a database, disk, or web service, for example.

Finally you should consider what this code should do:

```
var rb1 = ResultBuilder.PrepareParts()
var rb2 = rb1.PrepareDealer();
var rb1Built = rb1.Build();
var rb2Built = rb2.Build();
```

Often you see a lot of `return this;` in a fluent design. That leads to unexpected behaviour. If you create a pipeline of actions that gets executed when you call `Build()` and you always do a `return new ResultBuilder(...);` then you can build a solid fluent design.